# Click on a div Tag and Make it open another page/html file

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am having trouble getting a div tag to open another page/local html file when it is clicked.

I have a menu which consists of 5 buttons (div's) These buttons have a background image instead of a color because dream weaver doesn't have the font. Each button also has a hover over feature which changes the div to display an inverted image.

After googling how to make a whole div clickable and then for it to open the next page (local file) none of the methods has worked for me.

What i want to do for example is for when the "productsbutton" div is clicked the local html file called "Products.html" to open and display the content on that page.

My Source code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="CSS/design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="header"></div>

  <div id="menu">

    <div id="homebutton"></div>
    <div id="Productsbutton"></div>    
    <div id="Gallerybutton"></div>
    <div id="Menubutton"></div>
   <div id="Aboutbutton"></div>

  </div>
```

And my CSS is

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
    background-image:url(/Images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    Width:1400px;
    height:1400px;
}

#wrapper{
    Width:1000px;
    Height:1400px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:5px;
}


 #header{
     width:1000px;
     height:250px;
    background-image:url(/Images/banner.png);
}

#menu{
    width:1000px;
    height:35px;
    background-color:#1790e1;
    border-radius:5px;
}

   #homebutton{
    width:200px;
     height:35px;
      background-image:url(/Images/Menu_Buttons/Home%20Button.png);
     float:left;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease; 
     -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}

  #homebutton:hover{
background-image:url(/Images/Menu_Buttons/Home%20Button%20Hover.png);
filter: alpha(opacity=200);
opacity:2;
}

#Aboutbutton{
width:200px;
height:35px;
float:left;
background-image:url(/Images/Menu_Buttons/About.png);
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease; 
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#Aboutbutton:hover{
background-image:url(/Images/Menu_Buttons/About%20Hover.png);
filter: alpha(opacity=200);
opacity:2;
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}

 #Gallerybutton{
width:200px;
height:35px;
float:left;
background-image:url(/Images/Menu_Buttons/Gallery.png);
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease; 
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 }

 #Gallerybutton:hover{
background-image:url(/Images/Menu_Buttons/Gallery%20Hover.png);
filter: alpha(opacity=200);
opacity:2;
}

 #Menubutton{
width:200px;
height:35px;
float:left;
background-image:url(/Images/Menu_Buttons/Services.png);
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease; 
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#Menubutton:hover{
background-image:url(/Images/Menu_Buttons/Services%20Hover.png);
filter: alpha(opacity=200);
opacity:2;
}

#Productsbutton{
width:200px;
height:35px;
float:left;
background-image:url(/Images/Menu_Buttons/Products.png);
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease; 
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 color:#000000;

}

#Productsbutton:hover{
background-image:url(/Images/Menu_Buttons/Products%20Hover.png);
filter: alpha(opacity=200);
opacity:2;
 }
```

Comment: _None of the methods has worked for me_  - what methods have you tried?

Comment: the simplest method would be to use the `<a>` tag

Comment: where is body <body > tag ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `cursor: pointer;` for each clickable div to let users know it is clickable.

Then you should call `onclick()` even in each div to trigger the click and open respective page.

```
<div id="homebutton" onclick="openPage('Home.html')"> </div>
```

and in JS file,

```
 function openPage(pageUrl){
       window.open(pageUrl);
     }
```

For mode detail on how to open the page on another tab, here is the [link to W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open)

Answer (score 1):

To keep this solution strictly to html, I believe the answer should be to wrap an *a href* tag around the div.

```
<a href="Products.html">
    <div id="Productsbutton">Products</div>
</a>
```

Final version of your html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="CSS/design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="menu">

        <div id="homebutton">awdwa</div>
        <a href="Products.html">
          <div id="Productsbutton">Products</div>   
        </a>
        <div id="Gallerybutton">bbbb</div>
        <div id="Menubutton">ccc</div>
        <div id="Aboutbutton">ddd</div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can do it by adding in your id

```
       #homebutton{


      cursor: pointer;
}
```

OR

```
<a id="homebutton" href="#"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="Productsbutton" onclick="nav('Products.html')">Products</div>


function nav(page) {   
  window.location.href=page
}
```

Comment: where do i add the function, and do the "page" need to be replaced with "Products.html"?